# How to create conditional types in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, zod, trpc.io

So I have a Form component in react which takes props to handle various different situations. As I am using it for an online store it will mostly be sending input data to the server, and it needs to work with zod and infered tRPC typings. and I made this generic type, which I thought would mean I can pass either login data or signup data and it would work either way.

```
export type FormType<T extends SignUpForm | LoginForm> = T extends SignUpForm ? SignUpForm : LoginForm;
```

Instead I get this error in the form component

```
    value={form[types]} // form refers to state object 

    // const form: SignUpForm | LoginForm Element implicitly has an 'any' type 
    // because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'SignUpForm | LoginForm'
```

and this error in the parent element

```
    onResponse={handleRequest} // onResponse refers to Forms callback hook

Type '(data: SignUpForm) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 
  '(data: SignUpForm | LoginForm) => Promise<void>'.
     Types of parameters 'data' and 'data' are incompatible.
        Type 'SignUpForm | LoginForm' is not assignable to type 'SignUpForm'.
          Type 'LoginForm' is missing the following properties from type 'SignUpForm':
              firstname, lastname, day, month, yearts(2322)
```

and the types of each is just an object with strings as values.

This app was also created using create-t3-app if that helps.

I'm not sure If I've explained this well so please feel free to edit this post or ask questions

```
types.ts

export interface SignUpForm {
  firstname: string;
  lastname: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  day: string;
  month: string;
  year: string;
}

export interface LoginForm {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

export type FormType<T extends SignUpForm | LoginForm> = T extends SignUpForm ? SignUpForm : LoginForm;
```

```
hook.tsx

const useSetForm = (component: FormType<SignUpForm | LoginForm>) => {
  // component = object, is either SignupForm or LoginForm
  const [value, setForm] = useState(component);
  return [value, (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setForm((oldValue) => {
      return { ...oldValue, [event.target.name]: event.target.value };
    });
  },
  ] as const;
};
```

```
parent.tsx

const Signup: FC<SignupProps> = ({ }): JSX.Element => {

    const handleRequest = async (data: FormType<SignUpForm>) => {
        const res = await client.mutation('mongo.sign-up', data);
        console.log(res)
    }
    return (
        <Layout>
            <div className=''>
                <Form
                    formData={{ firstname: '', lastname: '', email: '', password: '', }}
                    target={'mongo.sign-up'}
                    buttons={['day', 'month', 'year']}
                    onResponse={handleRequest} />
                {/** pass types to create input fields, pass endpoint to target, buttons only needs definition for date of birth elements */}
                {/** onResponse returns complete form obj */}
            </div>
        </Layout>
    )
}

export default Signup
```

```
FormComponent.tsx

interface FormProps {
    formData: FormType<SignUpForm>
    target: `mongo.${'sign-up' | 'login'}` | `sendgrid.send-email`;
    onResponse: (data: SignUpForm | LoginForm) => Promise<void>
};


export const Form: FC<FormProps> = ({ target, onResponse, formData }): JSX.Element => {

    const [form, setForm] = useSetForm(formData);

    const handleCallback = useCallback((data: SignUpForm | LoginForm) => {
        onResponse(data)
        // pass data to parent elements
    }, [onResponse])

    return (
        <>
            <form onSubmit={handleCallback}>
                <>

                    {Object.keys(formData).map((types) => {
                        /** type is passed from parent elements,  */
                        return (
                            <input
                                key={types}
                                name={types}
                                value={form[types]}
                                type={types}
                                placeholder={types}
                                onChange={setForm} />)
                        //renders form text input elements  
                    })}

                </>
                <button type='submit' disabled={false}> Submit </button>
            </form>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: You seem to have several issues handling union type and records. Please add how you use `FormType`, and how you type `value`, `form`, `onResponse` and `handleRequest`. Or better: separate them into their own questions.

Comment: I think the scope of this question is a bit too broad. I support the suggestion to separate this into multiple questions. Just to offer a bit of help though: the first error is happening because the type returned by `Object.keys` is `string` not `keyof SignupForm | keyof LoginForm` which I think is what you need. See [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12253#issuecomment-263132208). The second error is because you have a signature mismatch. The form wants to be able to pass in `LoginForm | SignupForm` but the handler only supports `SignupForm`

Comment: Ah okay, Looks like I need to learn some more typescript, I appreciate the comments! I think I have a good sense of direction now. Once I gain some better understanding of whats actually going on I may separate the question. atm I'm not too sure which types and errors relate to which exactly...